# Xcode Swipe Gesture Recognizer Push Segue Moving Opposite Direction

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboardsegue, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Hello, I Have a navigation controller connected to a few view controllers connected via a swipe gesture push segue. When I swipe left, the screen goes left as expected and looks good. The problem comes about when I swipe right. Although the screen shows the next proper screen as it should when it swipes right, the animation looks as if it is swiping the opposite direction. I recorded it happening below:

https://vidd.me/bvW

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Push segues always come in from the right, that's just the way they work (and pops go out to the right)

Comment: As I suggested in a comment on your last question, you should look at using a UIPageViewController for your app. It will give you either a scroll or page curl animation that follows the direction of the swipe.

Comment: @rdelmar Any way I can change this? I would prefer to change the way it moves via storyboard but I doubt thats possible. Do you know what code and where I put that code to change the direction it moves when I swipe right.

Comment: There is no simple way to do that. You either need to write your own animation or use the UIPageViewController (or a paging enabled scroll view) as I suggested.